# JProgressBar updating on one thread, not on another

Tags: java

I created a popup window to show progress of something, and it is working fine with my downloader, everything is being updated.

```
private void downloadFile(String link, String directory, String name) throws IOException {
    task = new Downloader(link, directory, name);
    task.start();
}
```

and in the Downloader class:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                downloaded += length;
                bout.write(b, 0, length);

                int percent = (int) ((downloaded * 100) / fileLength);

                window.modify1("Downloading " + name + ".jar");
                window.modify2((int) downloaded, "Progress: " + percent + "% [" + String.valueOf(downloaded).subSequence(0, String.valueOf(downloaded).length() - 1) + "kb/" + String.valueOf(fileLength).subSequence(0, String.valueOf(fileLength).length() - 1) + "kb]");
            }

            is.close();
            bout.close();

            window.exit();

            Creator c = new Creator(directory, name);
            c.create();
            this.join();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, when I attempt to do almost the same in another thread, it does not work. Nothing in the popup window is being shown until the thread finishes.

```
LauncherThread t = new LauncherThread();
    t.start();

    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and in the LauncherThread class:

```
public void run() {     
    window.modify1("Fetching data...");
    window.modify2(0, "Progress: 0% [0/10]");

    Main.trust();
    window.modify2(1, "Progress: 10% [1/10]");

    Main.bukkitVersions = Finder.findBukkitVersions();
    window.modify2(2, "Progress: 20% [2/10]");

    Main.spigotVersions = Finder.findSpigotVersions();
    window.modify2(3, "Progress: 30% [3/10]");

    Main.vanillaVersion = Finder.findVanillaVersion();
    window.modify2(4, "Progress: 40% [4/10]");

    Main.bukkitLinks = new String[3];
    Main.bukkitLinks[0] = Finder.findDownloadLink("bukkit", "rb");
    window.modify2(5, "Progress: 50% [5/10]");

    Main.bukkitLinks[1] = Finder.findDownloadLink("bukkit", "beta");
    window.modify2(6, "Progress: 60% [6/10]");

    Main.bukkitLinks[2] = Finder.findDownloadLink("bukkit", "dev");
    window.modify2(7, "Progress: 70% [7/10]");

    Main.spigotLinks = new String[2];
    Main.spigotLinks[0] = Finder.findDownloadLink("spigot", "lastStable");
    window.modify2(8, "Progress: 80% [8/10]");

    Main.spigotLinks[1] = Finder.findDownloadLink("spigot", "lastBuild");
    window.modify2(9, "Progress: 90% [9/10]");

    Main.vanillaLink = Finder.findDownloadLink("vanilla", null);
    window.modify2(10, "Progress: 100% [10/10]");

    window.exit();
}
```

I'm still quite new to Java so I apologize for my ignorance.

Edit: I encased the t.start() method inside a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), and it works now. But the new problem is that the main class is no longer waiting for the LauncherThread to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the easy (and possibly bad) way. the initialize method is called in the LauncherThread after it finishes.

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new Main();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Main() {
    launch();
}

/**
 * Run launcher.
 */
private void launch() {
    LauncherThread t = new LauncherThread(this);
    t.start();
}
```

I pass the Main instance to the LauncherThread class through its constructor, so I can call the initialize method from there without having to use static access.

```
main.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the process of running into serious problems and I'm afraid your current solution doesn't solve the problem but just hides it.

The root problem is that Swing (as most comparable libs) isn't thread safe. So there must only one thread that accesses Swing components. That thread isn't arbitrary, but a special thread named EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

The consequences of that are:

- The initialization of your UI must be wrapped in a call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater or SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait
- If you do work in a separate thread that code must not touch your Progressbar directly. Instead it must dispatch updates to the progress bar through the two methods mentioned above.

If you don't do this right now and your code seams to work, it does not mean it will work tomorrow, or on a different machine, or when the weather changes or the government in china changes.

If you want, one thread to wait on another you should look into stuff like [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) just make sure you don't block the EDT, because when it is blocked nothing will get painted in the UI, so the application seems to be dead for the user. Again executing some code through invokeLater might solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

When i have to update Swing components from another Thread, then i'm doing it in

```
SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     //set new values
});
```

from Javadoc ot method:

```
Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread. This will happen after all pending AWT events have been processed. This method should be used when an application thread needs to update the GUI.
```

One more thing,.
You might consider doing your application via `SwingWorker`, those object are friendly with `EDT`. But remember, that they are executed in limited `ThreadPool`. I tried once to launch 50+ swing workers to update components of panel, however it worked only for first 10 of them. Probably could be changed to have them all running, but I've changed my approach.